# Modify the OpenCV Sticher class for speed

Tags: c++, opencv, panoramas, opencv-stitching

As I understood the OpenCV Stitcher class matches every input image with all other images, which allows to push unordered images yet get a correct output panorama. But which of course slows down exponentially the stitching process.

In my case the user will capture images moving the camera from left to right, so the order of the images is known.

How can I modify the Stitcher class to compare only side to side images, so no need to compare one against all when matching?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just rerun the stitcher on the stitched + new image.

Comment: @GPPK rerunning the stitcher on stitched + new image will compute features twice for the previous image (and in addition feature computation will strongly increase because the stitched images sizes will increase). 

Zhenya: try to understand the stitching pipeline and implement your own mosaicing algorithm optimized for your task. But beware that there is unavoidable drift if you match only image to image, without any global optimization.